# Slave steals IP meant for bonded interface

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet, cisco, network-bonding

I'm having an issue with this combo. I'm trying to set up an LACP bond using Ubuntu 16.04 and a Cisco SG-300.  I have the Cisco [configured for LACP on my two server's ports](https://imgur.com/a/UTu1g.jpg).  In Ubuntu I have the following config:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 10.0.0.5
gateway 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond-lacp-rate 1
bond-slaves eno1 eno2
xmit_hash_policy 0
```

This works but has one issue.  Whenever the system is started [eno1 seems to grab the static IP for bond0 10.0.0.5 and 10.0.0.5 is unreachable on the network.  If I do an 'ifdown eno1 && ifup eno1' the bond will grab 10.0.0.5 and start working normally.  Anyone have any clue as to why a slave device is grabbing the static IP meant for bond0 like that?

Answer (score 0):

There was a static configuration in /etc/dhcpcd.conf.  Not sure how that got there since I've always used static on this box.  I removed the offending lines from that file as well as removing the dhcpcd5 package all together and everything works fine now.